# How do I extend views properly in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a project which has 2 login forms, one for consumers and one for creators.
Both have different "post-login" areas.

But the view should look pretty similar, so I thought why not DRY-it™.
**QUESTION**: *Here is my solution, but I am sure there is a more elegant solution, please enlighten me if there is.*

*login.blade.php* (master template)

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('styles')
    {{ Html::style('css/login.css') }} // This also looks deprecated, how do I have a specific css only for this page?
@stop

@section('content')
<div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" action="{{ $loginAction }}"> //smells really bad
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login {{ $loginTitle }}</h2>
...
@endsection
```

*login_consumer.blade.php*

```
@extends('layout.login', [
    'loginTitle' => 'Consumer',
    'loginAction' => 'login_consumers'
    ])
```

*login_creator.blade.php*

```
@extends('layout.login', [
    'loginTitle' => 'Creators',
    'loginAction' => 'login_creators' 
    ])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common layout containing *header, body content* and *footer* 
are `app.blade.php` having `@yields('')` directive within allows you to inherit it as well as let you extend with new content through `@extends('')` directive. Also, you can append in master stylesheet through `@show` and `@parent` blade directive as below.

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
        @section('stylesheets')
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> <!-- this is master stylesheet -->
        @show
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Extending a layout

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/login.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('stylesheets')
    @parent

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

Now, explaining your second part of your question. Above case was about a common layout, but this case you are trying to achieve common body content so there's Components & Slots for that. Separate your common body content as a `component` and pass variable as a `slot`. This came from Laravel 5.4. Previously, it was called partials which was used through `@include('')` directive.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: The login body is not exactly the same, the action is different, does that change anything?

Comment: pass url/method as slot

Comment: what if I want to pass more variables? a slot isn't precise enough.

Comment: I didn't really get you

Comment: Can you show me an example with two parameters, without sending the whole form?

Comment: I'll just ask a different question about it, thanks anyways.